# Prepare seems to be stripping quotes from string so that it is not accepted by the mysql datetime field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, datetime

I would like to update a `DATETIME` mysql field using a php `STRING` in a prepared statement

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = ? where ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('si',$date,$id);
$date = "2013-12-04 00:00:00";  /*string '2013-12-04 00:00:00' (length=19)*/
$id = 4;
$stmt->execute();
```

I had expect that mysql should treat the statement as

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = '2013-12-04 00:00:00' where ID = ?; 
/*which works when directly entered*/
```

However I assume it is treating like

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = 2013-12-04 00:00:00 where ID = ?; 
/*giving the result of null*/
```

I have tried adding using the `STR_TO_DATE` mysql function to force it to treat the $date as a string and then convert it to `DATETIME`. ie

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = STR_TO_DATE(?,'%Y-%m-%d %T') where ID = ?"); 
/*again the result is null*/
```

Do I need to bind a quoted string? what am I missing?

Comment: date and id are declared after the bind!

Comment: Yeah, what mamdouh says. You are binding an empty value here

Comment: thanks for your replies @mamdouhalramadan
They bind first and then define here?
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
What have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no much sense to prepare it, bind it and then execute it in such an obscure way. Besides the problems outlined on the comments, consider changing it to:

```
$date = "2013-12-04 00:00:00";  /*string '2013-12-04 00:00:00' (length=19)*/
$id = 4;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = ? where ID = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($date, $id));
```

Besides, you were binding them wrong. You were using the prepare statement but then binding three values (or two values and a wrongly set parameter). Please [refer to the documentation for more info about binding parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Note that with [PHP >= 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17772534/938236) you can simply do:

```
$date = "2013-12-04 00:00:00";  /*string '2013-12-04 00:00:00' (length=19)*/
$id = 4;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE TABLE1 SET DATETIME1 = ? where ID = ?");
$stmt->execute([$date, $id]);
```