# Unexpected '[' error

Tags: php, arrays

I have an Index php page that contains a code that prints the values of an array `$a=['f','a','b'];`.

The code works fine on WAMP server on my computer however when I upload the page online on a server like 000webhost an error comes up that says there is unexpected '[' on line of the array. Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Post some PHP bro. Your error is most likely related to a difference in PHP versions.

Comment: Could be your PHP version. Yet, you could do `$a=array('f','a','b');` instead.

Comment: You need to supply us with more details on your problem if you want us to help.

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-array-square-brackets-and-array-difference).

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, it's valid code (which I didn't know). That means your server is running a PHP version lower than 5.4.

Comment: @halfer Yep, qualifies as a dupe. +1

Comment: **A:** => 000webhost's PHP Version is 5.2.17 - so, there you go ;) Use `$a=array('f','a','b');` - To find your PHP version on any server that supports PHP, use `<?php phpinfo();`

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP version doesn't support the `[]` notation, this kind of notation is available from PHP 5.4, use `$a = array('f','a','b');` instead.