# cakephp issue in fetching session data

Tags: php, session, cakephp

In my project i used following way to store and fetch data from session.

To write data:

```
$this->Session->write('data', array('title'=>'Abc'));
```

To read data:

```
$this->Session->read('data')['title'];
```

And it is still working fine at live server. 2 days ago i shifted my code to some other live server. Now this server is showing fatal error at
`$this->Session->read('data')['title'];` i.e unexpected [ ]

Then i google and found that there a some other way to get index e.g

```
$this->Session->read('data.title');
```

if  `$this->Session->read('data')['title']` is the wrong way then how it is still working at my old server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please mention your cakephp and php version.

Comment: This sounds like a difference in PHP versions. What version are you currently using and what was on the old server?

Comment: New server php version is : 5.3.32.0 and old server's : 5.4.162.0
You think its because of version ?

Answer (score 0):

`[]` is supported in `PHP 5.4`
This is a short syntax and in `PHP < 5.4` it won't work.

Source:
[PHP Difference between array() and []](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-array-square-brackets-and-array-difference)

Here's what you are looking for. I posted above content in a hurry.

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a temporary variable.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-101)


Example:

```
function getArray() {
    return array(1, 2, 3);
}

// on PHP 5.4
$secondElement = getArray()[1];

// previously
$tmp = getArray();
$secondElement = $tmp[1];
```