# getting value of array from certain index in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to get the value of an array type given a certain index. The array's values are

> $status = [1,2];

And I used these code to get the value:

> $task_state = $status[1];

But it actually thought $status is a string and returns

> '['

I know that this is actually quite simple, but I just can't seem to find the answer to my problem. Thank you

Comment: Your array gives an actual result. but if you face problem then try with declare $status as array `$status = array();` like this.

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Using `[]` to define arrays is only supported in PHP >= 5.4

Comment: it is 7.0.10 sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$status` defined as a string, you can return php value of it with [`eval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function like below:

```
$status = '[1,2]';
$status_array = eval('return ' . $status . ';');
$task_state = $status_array[0];
```

> **Caution**
>   The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

i try to copy your script and here what i get

```
$status = [1,2];
$task_state = $status[1];
var_dump($status);
exit;
```

the result is :

> array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-difference-between-array-and)=> int(2) }

can you give me line of your code for displaying '['.
may be your php version is the problem. See [refrence.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772534/php-difference-between-array-and)

Comment: is it when i echo $task_state sir

Comment: try to use `array(1, 2)` instead [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are saying that the values of your array:

```
$status  = array(1,2);
```

So to get a value from the array:

```
echo $tatus[0] . "and " . $tatus[1];
```

output:

1 and 2

Comment: actually i was trying to get post values from my android apps using $status = $_POST['state']; But I am already sure the value is [1,2], since I actually have tried to put and test it manually using postman